# My attachment is not getting sent when I try to send out a attchment

Tags: android

I have a file called card1.jpg stored in the assets folder.  When my program runs, it shows a paaper clip in the email and it seems like everything works when I press send.
But.... no attachment ever gets sent.

code:
            case R.id.butEmail:
                Intent msg = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                msg.setType("text/plain");
                msg.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"tedpottel@gmail.com"});
                msg.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "attach image");
                msg.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Just Feet");

```
            String rawFolderPath = "file://android_assets//card1.jpg";

            Uri emailUri = Uri.parse(rawFolderPath );
            msg.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, emailUri);
            msg.setType("application/jpg");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(msg, "Emailinng..."));

            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Two points:

- You are using wrong path to the asset folder. There should be three slashes. And you need not to use double slashes for the folder hierarchy. The correct path to the asset folder is:

> file:///android_assets/folder1/folder2/image.png"
>
> Your asset folder is local to your application(your process) so,
>   applications outside your process(application) cannot access your
>   asset folder.

Comment: still does not work, I have   String rawFolderPath = "file:///android_assets/card1.jpg"; any ideas???

Comment: you should place the data outside the apk... create a folder for your application in the sd card and place your images and other files there..